# Object on multiple slides but always on top

Tags: keynote

I am using KeyNote 12.1.1. I want an object to appear on all slides that use a particular slide layout. When I put the object in the slide layout, any objects on individual slides lie on top of that object. Is there a way of having the object on the slide layout appear always on top of other images on each slide?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have objects on the slide layout *always* be on top, but you can perform normal layering operations such as ‘Bring to Front’ work with slide layout objects by enabling ‘Allow layering’:

> If you want slides based on this layout to allow objects to be layered under slide layout objects, click the background of the slide (so that nothing is selected), then select “Allow layering” in the Format  sidebar.

https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/tan7a2b69972/mac